# Condition Probability - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability, density-function

I am reviewing some notes of mine and refreshing myself with some statistics and I came across a problem that asks me to calculate $P(X>1|Y>1)$ for the random variables $X$ and $Y$ whose joint probability density function is given by:

\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x,y) & = & \begin{cases}
ye^{-y(x+1)} & x>0,\,y>0\\
0 & otherwise
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray*}

I thought of two ways of computing this and I thought that regardless of which approach I took, I should end up with the same answer, but I'm getting two different final answers.  **I'm hoping someone could help me figure out which is the right answer AND why the other answer is not correct.**

### **Method 1:**

\begin{eqnarray}
P(X>1|Y>1) & = & \frac{P(X>1,\,Y>1)}{P(Y>1)}\nonumber \\
 & = & \frac{\int_{1}^{\infty}\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x,y)dxdy}{\int_{1}^{\infty}f(y)dy} &&&&&&&&&&&(1)
\end{eqnarray}

To calculate this, I first find the marginal pdf, $f(y)$ for the
denominator in this last term:

\begin{eqnarray*}
f(y) & = & \int_{0}^{\infty}ye^{-y(x+1)}dx\\
 & = & ye^{-y}\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-yx}dx\\
 & = & \left(ye^{-y}\right)\left(\left.-\frac{1}{y}e^{-yx}\right|_{x=0}^{x=\infty}\right)\\
 & = & \left(e^{-y}\right)\left(\left.-e^{-yx}\right|_{x=0}^{x=\infty}\right)\\
 & = & \left(e^{-y}\right)\left(0+1\right)\\
 & = & e^{-y}
\end{eqnarray*}

so $f(y)=e^{-y}$ for $y\in(0,\infty)$. So using this, we now calculate
$P(Y>1)$ (the denominator term in $(1)$ above):

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(Y>1) & = &\int_{1}^{\infty}f(y)dy\\
 & = &\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-y}dy\\
 & = & \left.-e^{-y}\right|_{y=1}^{y=\infty}\\
 & = & 0+e^{-1}\\
 & = & e^{-1}
\end{eqnarray*}

Now, we compute the numerator in $(1)$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(X>1,\,Y>1) & = & \int_{1}^{\infty}\int_{1}^{\infty}ye^{-y(x+1)}dxdy\\
 & = & \int_{1}^{\infty}ye^{-y}\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-xy}dxdy\\
 & = & \int_{1}^{\infty}ye^{-y}\left(\left.-\frac{1}{y}e^{-yx}\right|_{x=1}^{x=\infty}\right)dy\\
 & = & \int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-y}\left(0+e^{-y}\right)dy\\
 & = & \int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-2y}dy\\
 & = & \frac{1}{2}e^{-2}
\end{eqnarray*}

Assembling the numerator and denominator components should give us
the final answer:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{P(X>1,\,Y>1)}{P(Y>1)} & = & \frac{\frac{1}{2}e^{-2}}{e^{-1}} & = & \frac{1}{2}e^{-2}e^{1} & = & \frac{1}{2}e^{-1}
\end{eqnarray*}

So, on to method 2:

### **Method 2**

This method differs from Method 1 in that I compute (I think) $f(x|y)$
and then compute the desired probability from the conditional pdf:

\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x|y) & = & \frac{f(x,y)}{f(y)}\\
 & = & \frac{ye^{-y(x+1)}}{e^{-y}}\\
 & = & ye^{-y(x+1)}e^{y}\\
 & = & \begin{cases}
ye^{-xy} & x>0,\,y>0\\
0 & otherwise
\end{cases}
\end{eqnarray*}

So, now, to calculate $P(X>1|Y>1)$, I compute the following:

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(X>1|Y>1) & = & \int_{1}^{\infty}\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x|y)dxdy\\
 & = & \int_{1}^{\infty}\int_{1}^{\infty}ye^{-xy}dxdy\\
 & = & \int_{1}^{\infty}y\int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-xy}dxdy\\
 & = & \int_{1}^{\infty}y\left(\left.-\frac{1}{y}e^{-xy}\right|_{x=1}^{x=\infty}\right)dy\\
 & = & \int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\left.-e^{-xy}\right|_{x=1}^{x=\infty}\right)dy\\
 & = & \int_{1}^{\infty}\left(e^{-y}\right)dy\\
 & = & \left.-e^{-y}\right|_{y=1}^{y=\infty}\\
 & = & 0+e^{-1}\\
 & = & e^{-1}
\end{eqnarray*}

So, with Method 1 I get $P(X>1|Y>1)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-1}$ and with Method
2 I get $P(X>1|Y>1)=e^{-1}$. So, which one is right AND, if I haven't
just made a simple error somewhere, why don't both of these methods
return the same result? Is there a fundamental flaw in Method 1 or
Method 2?

Answer (score 2):

Both methods give you the same answer, as they should.

In the first method, as you said,

\begin{align}
P(X>1\mid Y>1)&=\frac{P(X>1,Y>1)}{P(Y>1)}
\\&=\frac{1}{P(Y>1)}\iint\mathbf1_{x>1,y>1}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy 
\end{align}

In the second method,

\begin{align}
P(X>1\mid Y>1)&=\int\mathbf1_{x>1}\color{blue}{f_{X\mid Y>1}(x)}\,dx
\\&=\int\mathbf1_{x>1}\left(\color{blue}{\int\mathbf1_{y>1}\frac{ f(x,y)}{P(Y>1)}\,dy}\right)\,dx
\end{align}

Your formulation of method 2 was not quite correct, hence the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

note that $P(X>1|Y>1)$ is not equal $\int_{1}^{\infty} \int_{1}^{\infty} f(x|y) dx dy$ see modern probability for more information.

it is equal  $\int_{1}^{\infty}  f(x|Y>1) dx$ . you drive($\frac{d}{dx}$) from $F(x|Y>1)$ to calculate $f(x|Y>1)$.

so,

$P(X>1|Y>1)=\int_{1}^{\infty}  f(x|Y>1) dx =\int_{1}^{\infty}  \frac{f(x,Y>1)}{f(Y>1)} dx= \frac{1}{f(Y>1)} \int_{1}^{\infty}  f(x,Y>1)=\frac{1}{\int_{1}^{\infty} f(y)dy} \int_{1}^{\infty} \int_{1}^{\infty} f(x,y) dx dy=\frac{1}{\int_{1}^{\infty} f(y)dy} \int_{1}^{\infty} \int_{1}^{\infty} f(x|y)f(y) dx dy=\frac{1}{\int_{1}^{\infty} f_Y(t)dt} \int_{1}^{\infty} \int_{1}^{\infty} f(x|y)f(y) dx dy=\int_{1}^{\infty} \int_{1}^{\infty} f(x|y)\frac{f(y)}{\int_{1}^{\infty} f_Y(t)dt}  dx dy \neq \int_{1}^{\infty} \int_{1}^{\infty} f(x|y) dx dy$.

also

$P(X>1|Y>1) = \frac{1}{\int_{1}^{\infty} f(y)dy} \int_{1}^{\infty} \int_{1}^{\infty} f(x,y) dx dy =\frac{1}{e^{-1}} \frac{1}{2}e^{-2}=\frac{1}{2}e^{-1} $